# how to replace some specific content of a file with the first line of another file?

Tags: text-processing

I have two files: `one.txt`and `sample.txt`

`one.txt`has these following contents:

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
DDDD
```

`sample.txt`has some specific contents like following:

```
>>XXXXXXX<<
```

how can I:

1. replace the "XXXXXXX" with the first line content of the `one.txt`?
2. delete the first line of the `one.txt`?
3. rename the `one.txt` into `AAAA.txt`?

in the linux command line?

[image]

Comment: Your example `one.txt` has empty spaces at the end of each line. Is that how your real file is? Do we need to remove those spaces before adding the line to sample.txt?

Comment: yes,my real file has many lines,and each line has empty space at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
## save the first line of one.txt in the variable $string
string=$(head -n1 one.txt)
## delete the first line of one.txt
sed -i '1d' one.txt
## replace the Xs in `>>XXXXX<<` with the contents of `$string` 
## and save as the new file "$string.txt" (AAAA.txt)
sed "s/>>XXXXXXX<</>>$string<</" sample.txt > $string.txt
```

Note that this assumes there is only one occurrence of `>>XXXXXX<<` on any line of `sample.txt`. If there can be more than one per line, then the command above will only replace the 1st one on each line. To replace all of them, use this instead:

```
sed "s/>>XXXXXXX<</>>$string<</g" sample.txt > $string.txt
```

---

Your original question had spaces at the end of each line in `one.txt`. If this is the case with your real file and you need to remove the spaces before adding to `sample.txt`, use this:

```
string=$(head -n1 one.txt | sed 's/ *$//')
```

Then the same commands as above.

Comment: great thanks for answering my question in such a short time

Comment: great thanks to you again,your scrpits works excellent!!!!!

Comment: @CantaTam hang on, this answer assumed that you want to keep the spaces at the end of the line.  So this would replace `>>XXXXXXX<<` with `>>AAAA   <<` and not `>>AAAA<<`, is that what you want?

Comment: Anyway, if you do need to remove the spaces, see udpated answer.

Comment: the empty space doesn't affect the final result. I am making opensource fonts,and your scripts helps me generate thousands of pdf templates in JUST SEVERAL minutes. If without your help ,the time would be SEVERAL WEEKS.

Comment: @CantaTam ah, great! Glad to hear I helped! If this answer solves your problem, please consider [accepting it](//$$SITEURL/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on [the checkmark on the left](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/203101). That will mark the question as answered and is the way that thanks are conveyed on the Stack Exchange sites.